# How to determine the WCF address being hosted by a windows service?

Tags: wcf

Basically I have a WCF hosted in multiple Windows Services (before anyone asks IIS cannot be used for multiple and very valid reasons). I have a control application that allows the Windows Services to be stop/started/restarted in special orders (with several differing parameters) etc but I need some way of knowing what address each windows service is hosting i.e. a function that either

- given an address e.g.
  http://me.us.com:8701/MyWCFService/MyWCFConfig returns service
  name/PID

or better still

- given a PID/service name returns the address(es) hosted e.g.
  http://me.us.com:8701/MyWCFService/MyWCFConfig

Any ideas, code or thoughts on this folks?

Thanks in advance for taking the time,

Brian

Comment: Will storing the address in database work?

Comment: We have various methods of connecting the two like the database example you have given but we would prefer a method that can detect the link in the form Windows itself does e.g. like Windows connects A Windows Service with its PID in WQL SELECT ProcessID FROM WIN32_SERVICE etc if at all possible so data is not duplicated and therefore the possibility of being invalid and adding complexity if not required.

Comment: I was about to recommend implementing your own ServiceHost to collect the hosting information. I am not aware of WMI events that will let you dig this info